# How to answer a question that has been asked multiple times?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, duplicate-questions

In searching for an answer to a PHP/PDO problem I have encountered, I discovered 2 questions that are very similar in nature ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717336/pdo-bindparam-using-an-array-not-working-as-assumed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677752/pdo-bindparam-not-working-in-loop)) (there are other similar ones as well). Both of these questions have answers that present workarounds for the problem rather than explaining why the problem occurs and offering a solution. On further looking into the problem, I have figured out what exactly is causing it and am interested in sharing the explanation and how to fix code that has the issue.

My question is, should I attempt to find all the questions that have been asked about this problem and answer them all, or is it OK/better to post a question with a similar title (and an MCVE) and self-answer it? Or should I just not clutter SO with a bunch of answers that will probably not get read (the questions have been marked answered) or one more question that is a duplicate?

Comment: Answer one, flag/close the others as a duplicate if you believe they are duplicates.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the advice. Would you recommend answering the first one or the most recently active?

Comment: Answer the one you feel was most well-asked. Since the others will redirect to it, the best question should have the answer

Comment: @nick as a general rule, don't mind about time (most recent, less recent, still active etc...) in SO (and in other SE sites as well). If the purpose of SO is to be a knowledge database, we need to have the best Q/A pair as the original, regardless the time, and then closing the other ones as duplicates, as advised in the comments above.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Also consider editing the question to make it more clear when creating a canonical. If both question are equally well-asked, take into account how old they are and how many views and backlinks they have.

Comment: @Bergi how can I find how many backlinks a question has?

Comment: @Nick They show up in a "Linked" section in the sidebar, above the "Related" questions.

Comment: @Bergi obviously I've not been looking at popular questions as I don't think I've seen that section yet! :)

Comment: I don't understand why you think "should I attempt to find all the questions that have been asked about this problem and **answer them all**" would be at all acceptable.  That runs counter-intuitive to the very existence of the duplicate tagging system.

Comment: @zero298 You are of course absolutely correct. Put it down to the fact that I've only been using SO for about 5 weeks. I would edit the post to reflect that but I think that other comments make have made the point about what is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Nick Gosh darn you got a lot of rep quickly... 0_o

Comment: @Clonkex yeah possibly I'm spending a little bit too much time on SO...

Comment: @Nick [https://stackoverflow.com/users/2288578/clonkex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2288578/clonkex) Look at the activity, you can see where I got obsessed with SO for a while... :P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First off, if you think the questions are duplicates, consider the best phrased question as the target, and flag the other as closure of the former. If both questions have good answers on them, you can use a custom moderator flag to request merging the answers to the target.

As to the answer: if you think one of the questions is good and general enough, or can be edited to be as such without changing the original meaning too much: answer that one. If both questions are not general enough to your problem, or require much more information in the question etc for your answer to be applicable to the question, create a new (canonical) question and flag both of the other questions as duplicate of yours.

I have done the latter once for a common problem, which was usually phrased in a sense related to their code/variables, whereas it was a rounding-display problem. Since I could not edit the questions to be general enough without destroying the original question, I elected to write [my own Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49191571/5211833) and duplicate-vote the other two to it.

As [zero298](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366010/how-to-answer-a-question-that-has-been-asked-multiple-times#comment574976_366010) commented, don't answer all the duplicate questions. That goes against the idea of Stack Overflow that knowledge can be found in a single place, not all over. Thus, flag all duplicate questions you find with either the best, or, if you decide to write one, your own Q/A.